# In FME Desktop, I have a custom coordinate system, I was confused how to translate it for MyCoordSysDefs.fme

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form

I have a custom coordinate system that I was confused how to translate it to the MyCoordSysDefs.fme for use in Safe Desktop. Here's how it is represented in the prj file.

PROJCS["Lumos_Projection_Foot",
GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
SPHEROID["Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980",6378137,298.2572221008916]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-80],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",4921259.843],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["Foot_US",0.30480060960121924]]

I read over the help for FME DEsktop, but the I did not know how to translate it because it had two units and so many Parameters.
I appricate any help. Thanks

Comment: http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Workbench/Default.htm#Adding_Custom_Transformation.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entry for the above projection in `MyCoordSysDefs.fme` should look like this:

```
COORDINATE_SYSTEM_DEF  NAD83-LUMOS        \
   DESC_NM "NAD83 Lumos Projection USFT"  \
   DT_NAME NAD83                          \
   PROJ TM                                \
   UNIT FOOT                              \
   PARM1 -80.0                            \
   SCL_RED 0.9996                         \
   ORG_LAT 0.0                            \
   X_OFF 4921259.843                      \
   Y_OFF 0.0
```

You can change the `COORDINATE_SYSTEM_DEF` and `DESC_NM` to whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, Safe Software now publish a website that converts ESRI WKT from a PRJ into an FME recognized file.
See [Define Custom Coordinate System](https://demos-safe-software.fmecloud.com/fmedatastreaming/Coordsys/Start.fmw?)

The results when inputting your PRJ are as follows:

```
COORDINATE_SYSTEM_DEF NAD83-LUMOS \
DESC_NM "NAD83 Lumos Projection USFT" \
DT_NAME NAD83 \
ORG_LAT 0 \
PARM1 -80 \
PROJ TM \
QUAD 1 \
SCL_RED 0.9996000000 \
UNIT FOOT \
X_OFF 4921259.843 \
Y_OFF 0
```

Which confirms the results by Mintx.